# Merge 2 arraycollection - Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex

How I actually merge both together?

one arraycollection would contain value of 0...30 with Object name "sxx" with another arraycollection retrieve from database.

Comment: Can you get more specific? Are you trying to merge objects with unique keys in such a way that, given two such keys, one will take precedence over the other? Or are you just trying to concatenate two ArrayCollections?

Answer (score 5):

HI!

Solution 1:

```
private function mergeArrays(a:ArrayCollection, b:ArrayCollection):ArrayCollection
{
    for each(var item:Object in b)
    {
        a.addItem(item);
    }
    return a;
 }
```

Solution 2:

```
var a:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([1,2]);
var b:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([3,4]);

a = new ArrayCollection(a.toArray().concat(b.toArray()));
```

Have fun!
:P

Answer (score 0):

```
var first:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(['aa','aaa','aaaa']);
var second:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(['bb','bb','bb']);
first.source = first.source.concat(second.source);
```